# How to give FirefoxDrive and gecko driver in qaf applicaiton.properties to do execution in firefox

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, qaf

I was trying to execute my [QAF framework](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) in my local Firefox( Version 61) and I need to know how to call out firefox browser from QAF application.

```
driver.name=geckodriver
webdriver.gecko.driver = C:/DRIVERS/geckodriver.exe
```

Above one did not work. Do I need to give `driver.name=firefoxDriver`. Even then it did not work on QAF. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set following properties for firefox:

```
driver.name=firefoxDriver
system.webdriver.gecko.driver=C:/DRIVERS/geckodriver.exe
```

You also can provide relative path like below:

```
system.webdriver.gecko.driver=servers/geckodriver.exe
```

In above case driver executable assumed under /servers.
After setting above properties if you are facing any issue then you need to check geckodriver and selenium webdriver version is compatible with the version of firefox. If you are updating selenium version above 3+ make sure to use selenium-support version 3.0.0 or use [qaf latest version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.qmetry/qaf) (2.1.14-RC1 is the latest at present).

Comment: Thanks. Now I am able to load the browser but the URL is not entering in firefox browser. I am getting this error - "main: Driver: firefoxDriver 
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
startup on aushelper@mozilla.org version 2.0"

Comment: Also in the same test I am seeing "Failed to connect to binary" error too

Unable to create driver instance in 1st attempt with retry timeout of 200 seconds. You can check/set value of 'driver.init.retry.timeout' appropriately to set retry timeout on driver initialization failure.Unable to Create Driver Instance for firefox: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin) on port 7055; process output follows:

Comment: This is more related to webdriver compatibility. Check you have correct  [version and executable of gecko driver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) for your environment and firefox version. Keep in mind that for windows there are 64bit and 32bit versions available for driver. It should match with your firefox version (32 or 64).

Comment: I did try with Firefox window 63.0.1 (64-bit), geckodriver-v0.23.0-win64 with selenium version 3.14.0 and qaf version 2.1.14-RC1 and it worked fine for me.